# Pycharm rename file and class at same time

Tags: python, pycharm

I am facing some problem.
In pycharm ide I has operation to rename a class.
If class name and file name same (for example apple.py and class Apple) ide automatically rename both class and file. (i have checkbox "Rename containing file")

But, when i have a bit different name, for example
red_apple.py and class RedApple ide dont help me to rename both file and class. Is there any ideas, how to fix this?

Comment: I'd recommend just manually renaming the file after if that's what you want. But in any case, it's unusual to have a 1-to-1 correspondence between module names and class names in Python. Modules should be namespaces for semantically related things. Having a module name and a class name that are too similar strongly suggests that one of them is being named redundantly / you're not taking advantage to good namespacing. For example, you'd usually have an `apples` (`fruits`?) module that defines both the classes `RedApple` and `GreenApple`, not one module for each.

Comment: [Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)

Comment: @Brian61354270 Good general advice, although there are notable counter-examples, like `datetime.datetime` and `bs4.BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, the standard library is littered with them! `abc.ABC`, `bisect.bisect`, `copy.copy` `dis.dis`, `enum.Enum`, `fcntl.fcntl`, `gettext.gettext`, ... I wonder if we could finish the alphabet :). But they're the exceptions that prove the rule, and all of them still follow the "larger grouping of semantically related things" rule

Comment: @Brian61354270 True. Although those are mostly functions (except for `Enum`), not classes. And it's mainly that they couldn't come up with a better name for the module that didn't happen to duplicate its most commonly used function (although `copy.copy()` might be better named `copy.shallowcopy()` to contrast with `copy.deepcopy()`).